# Install pypy (or other python) to be the main python

Tags: installation, python

I want to replace the default CPython (Python) with pypy (1.8).

Will this cause a problem? (I ask because python seems to be an important component in Ubuntu.).

I've built pypy and have installed it on a virtual machine of Ubuntu (I'm testing this idea out before I do it to my actual machine. So while we can try thing my intention is to accomplish this in "real life" as it were.).

Pypy is usable from the anywhere in the system via `pypy` as opposed to `python`.

```
pypy my_python_script.py
```

It seems to be installed fine and seems usable.

Now, I want to make it so that any time I want to use python, it'll assume I mean pypy.

For example, I installed Django in to pypy but when I try to run `django-admin.py` it has no idea what I'm talking about. I imagine I could accomplish this part by adding wherever django-admin.py is to my `$HOME` variable.

That, for now, is aside the point.

So, my question is how do I replace standard python with my own preferred version -- in this case, pypy.

---

I'm revising my question based on the answer thus far -- **that replacing CPython in whole is not a good idea** as it could foobar the system.

I've read a bit on virtualenv -- looks good but it doesn't seem to answer my question (or, I'm missing how).

I want to use pypy for my work in python. Development work for things like, Django, Google App Engine and other such nonsense. (I realize there could be a compatibility issue, I'll address those with unit tests or some other means. Just know, it's beside the point at the moment.)

So, keeping this in mind, say I want to use pypy instead of python. And for `./django-admin.py` to work globally, it'd have to be installed with the system's python. How might I configure the system to support these "global" python scripts from either pypy or the main system python?

Comment: could some one add a pypy tag to this, please. I could not 'create' the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a good idea to mess with system python because, as you have noticed, Ubuntu uses python widely so any change may render your system unstable.

Moreover, as a developer, I can tell you that globally installing third-party libraries into your system Python is not a good idea either - everything will start falling apart as soon as you have two projects which require different versions of Django, for example.

Luckily, Python has very good tools for creating isolated environments which may be completely independent from the system Python.

Have a look at [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and [zc.buildout](http://www.buildout.org/) (along with djangorecipe) for a civilized solution to your problem. :)

**UPDATE:** Very briefly, here's how zc.buildout would solve your problem:

You create a directory where you put [bootstrap.py](http://svn.zope.org/%2acheckout%2a/zc.buildout/trunk/bootstrap/bootstrap.py) and `buildout.cfg` file which contains

```
[buildout]
parts = django
versions = versions

[versions]
django = 1.2.5

[django]
recipe = djangorecipe
settings = development
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}
project = mymegaapp
```

Then you run `/path/to/python/interpreter/python bootstrap.py`, at which point your buildout "remembers" which python interpreter you used. It also creates a `bin` directory where all your "global" scripts will be auto-generated. Then you run `bin/buildout`, which downloads and installs Django of specified version, creates an empty project called "mymegaapp" etc. After it's finished, you'll find `django` command in the `bin` directory which is equivalent to django-admin.py, so you can run

```
bin/django syncdb
bin/django runserver
```

etc. You never have to worry to remember to use the correct interpreter. Of course, this is just a very small part of what you can do with buildout... just think about putting buildout.cfg into a VCS so you can re-build the application with all the dependencies at exact versions, even in a few years from now... or about having multiple configs for different "deployment configurations" :)

For a quick example how to do this with virtualenv you can have a look [at this article](http://tumblr.intranation.com/post/766290325/python-virtualenv-quickstart-django) - the instructions should work apart from the very first part - you'll need to install setuptools with your pypy, not with the 'standard' interpreter. Then you'll use `python` script generated in your sandbox's `bin` directory:

```
cd myapp
../venv/bin/python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

*(I have a feeling the question becomes less and less relevant to Ubuntu... should we ask for it to be migrated to stackoverflow?)*